# Problem with Fortran 90 program for linear system resolution through Cramer's rule

Tags: matrix, fortran, linear-algebra, fortran90

I am writing this linear system solver for an university assignment, and I have incurred in quite a weird problem. I have defined a recursive function
for calculating the determinant of a square matrix through Laplace's first theorem, which seems to work just fine in all the test cases I have tried.
In the body of the program I then use a do loop to implement Cramer's rule for linear systems, calculating the determinant for the n matrices with the ith column substituted with the known terms of the system. At this moment the determinant function I have defined seems to start misbehaving, and in a pretty specific way: testing with dimension 3 matrices, the det of the matrix with the first column substituted is correct, but that of the second and third is the sum of what is supposed to be the correct determinant and the determinants of the preceding matrices. I am setting the value of the variable where I store this data to zero at every iteration of the loop (and there are no summation operators in that fragment of code so I can't see where this behavior would arise from). Like I said, I have tried quite a lot of test cases so it would seem unlikely that it is just a random occurrence. Since I am no expert in Fortran (nor in programming in general) it very well could be some very simple mistake I am completely missing, but for now I haven't been able to spot it.

```
module functions
implicit none

contains

recursive function determinant (m, mat2) result (det) !nel definire le funzioni recursive è necessario chiamare la proprietà RESULT
    implicit none                                     !e dichiarare esplicitamente la variabile che la funzione ritorna.
    integer, intent(in)                :: m
    real,  intent(in), dimension(m, m) :: mat2
    integer                            :: x, sgn = -1
    real                               :: submat(m-1, m-1), det
    
    if (m == 1) then
        det = mat2(1, 1)
    else if(m == 0) then
        det = 0
    else if(m==2) then
        det = mat2(1,1)*mat2(2,2) - mat2(1,2)*mat2(2,1) !calcolo esplicito del determinante di una matrice quadrata di dimensione 2
    else 
        do x =1, m !il teorema di laplace viene applicato alla prima colonna della matrice

            submat(1:x-1, 1:m-1) = mat2(1:x-1, 2:m) !si definisce la sottomatrice associata attraverso
            submat(x:m-1, 1:m-1) = mat2(x+1:m, 2:m) !lo slicing dell'array multidimensionale di partenza

            det = det + (sgn**(x+1))*mat2(x, 1) * determinant(m-1, submat) !implementazione ricorsiva del primo teorema di Laplace
            
        end do
    end if

end function determinant
end module functions


program gaia_leita
use functions
implicit none
real(KIND=16)     :: start, finish
integer           :: n, i, j, h
real, allocatable :: matrix(:,:), sol_vec(:), known_terms(:)
real, allocatable :: cramer_matrix(:,:)
real              :: deter, cr_det = 0


write(*,*) "Questo programma calcola il determinante di una matrice M NxN"
write(*,*) "Inserire la dimensione della matrice:"
read(*,*) n
allocate(matrix(n, n))
write(*,*) "Inserire le entrate della matrice M riga per riga:"
do i = 1, n
    do j = 1, n
       read(*, *) matrix(i, j)
    end do
end do

call cpu_time(start)

deter = determinant(n, matrix)

write(*, *) "Il determinante della matrice M è: |M| = ", deter

write(*,*) "Per risolvere il sistema lineare M*v = b inserire i valori dei termini noti b1...bn:"

allocate(known_terms(n))
allocate(sol_vec(n))
allocate(cramer_matrix(n, n))


do i = 1, n
    
    read(*, *) known_terms(i)
    
end do

!metodo di cramer per la risoluzione dei sistemi lineari

if(deter == 0) then
    write(*,*) "Il sistema non soddisfa le ipotesi del metodo di Cramer"
else
    cramer_matrix = matrix
    do i = 1, n
        cr_det = 0 
        cramer_matrix = matrix
        cramer_matrix(:, i) = known_terms(:)

        do j = 1, n
            do h=1, n
                write(*,*) cramer_matrix(j, h)
            end do
        end do
        
        cr_det = determinant(n, cramer_matrix)

        write(*, *) cr_det

        write(*,*)

        sol_vec(i) = cr_det/ deter

        write(*,*)
    end do
end if



Write(*,*) "La soluzione del sistema è il vettore x = ( "
do i = 1, n
    write(*,*) sol_vec(i), " "
end do
write(*,*) ")"

deallocate(matrix)
deallocate(known_terms)
deallocate(sol_vec)
deallocate(cramer_matrix)

call cpu_time(finish)

write(*,*) "Time elapsed:", finish-start, "seconds"

read(*,*)
end program gaia_leita
```

(ignore the comments, I am italian) Thanks a lot, I hope I'm not wasting anyone's time. Here is a test run:

```
     Questo programma calcola il determinante di una matrice M NxN
 Inserire la dimensione della matrice:
3
 Inserire le entrate della matrice M riga per riga:
2
3
6
-5
-3
5
1
0
2
 Il determinante della matrice M ├¿: |M| =    51.0000000
 Per risolvere il sistema lineare M*v = b inserire i valori dei termini noti b1...bn:
3
2
4
   3.00000000
   3.00000000
   6.00000000
   2.00000000
  -3.00000000
   5.00000000
   4.00000000
   0.00000000
   2.00000000
   102.000000


   2.00000000
   3.00000000
   6.00000000
  -5.00000000
   2.00000000
   5.00000000
   1.00000000
   4.00000000
   2.00000000
  -17.0000000


   2.00000000
   3.00000000
   3.00000000
  -5.00000000
  -3.00000000
   2.00000000
   1.00000000
   0.00000000
   4.00000000
   34.0000000


 La soluzione del sistema ├¿ il vettore x = (
   2.00000000
 -0.333333343
  0.666666687
 )
```

The values following the substituted matrices are the determinants as given by the program: only the first one is correct, while the other ones are the sum of the correct value and the preceding values.

Comment: Looks like you need to set  cr_det = 0 at the start of each calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check out the links. Unfortunately, i actually do set cr_det = 0 at the start of the loop. Maybe I should do it some other way? I don’t see why it wouldn’t work though

Comment: In the end I managed to solve the problem on my own, it was actually something like you said, I had to set the return value of the  function determinant to 0 inside the function. Thanks a lot anyways for the help! Nest time I have a question I will make it more coincise.

Comment: I still have no idea why you would need that though, if someone has he is welcome to answer anyways